# Поиск слова и вывод с последующими строками

Tags: python, строки, файлы, поиск, работа-с-текстом

Добрый день нужно произвести поиск слова в объёмном txt. файле, но результат должен включать в себя как строку с искомым словом так и следующие три строки.

Данный скрипт выводит только одну строку со словом:

```
with open("dz.txt") as openfile:
for line in openfile:
    for part in line.split():
        if "kotik" in part:
            print (part)
```

Видно что в консоли поиска выдало только первую строку, а нужны все.
[image: Видно что в консоли поиска выдало только первую строку, а нужны все.]

Comment: добавьте пример текстового файла

Comment: верю) но вот `но и рисование` это не следующие 3 строки. будет отлично если вы добавите пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: Добавил извениясь,) тоесть в результатах я должен получить все три строки вбив в поиск только algebra

Comment: Так видимо остаться после уроков и сделать работу по быстрому не получается, начну с того что я только начал изучать программирование и решил помочь себе этим в работе, спасибо за ответ но я ничего не понял, думал все будет выглядеть как один скрипт, рано я в дебри залез, спасибо за ответ еще раз, вы прекрасны

Comment: @Саша а в каком месте непонятно?..

Comment: есть конкретное искомое слово "Котик" есть три строки идущие по очереди абзацем! котик идет гулять, на улицу, темной ночью. Мой скрипт выдает в  результате поиска только Котик идет гулять, мне нужно чтобы в результате выдал все три строки. Послединий скрипт в ответе, ничего не происходит,((

Comment: 'Котик' != 'котик' в python... добавьте, все-таки, содержимое файла (частично), запрос и ожидаемый вывод?

Comment: исправил, извиняюсь за неконструктив))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраните строки файла в [список](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) `lessons_list`, например:

```
with open('dz.txt') as f:
    lessons_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

используя [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) и сразу очищая строки от символов переноса строки.

Сравнивайте искомое слово с каждым элементом в [нумерованном списке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Если найдете совпадение, выводите [срез списка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) длиной 3, начиная от найденного:

```
def search(lessons_list, search):
    for i, lesson in enumerate(lessons_list):
        if search in lesson:
            print(lessons_list[i:i+3])
```

Для списка:

```
lessons_list = ['geometry', 'algebra', 'physics', 'art', 'english', 'biology']
```

Вывод:

```
>>> search(lessons_list, 'algebra')
['algebra', 'physics', 'art']

>>> search(lessons_list, 'english')
['english', 'biology']

>>> search(lessons_list, 'blablalesson')
```

Или, если нужен просто вывод в столбик - заменить `print` на `print(*lessons_list[i:i+3], sep='\n')`, тогда:

```
>>> search(lessons_list, 'geometry')
geometry
algebra
physics
```

В последнем случае ничего не выведет, т.к. ничего не найдено.

PS Прелесть срезов - они не бросаются исключениями ;)

UPD простой, неуниверсальный, скучный скрипт, "который ищет только одну строку":

```
with open('dz.txt') as f:
    lines_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    for i, line in enumerate(lines_list):
        if 'алгебра' in line.lower():
            print(*lines_list[i:i+3], sep='\n')
```

Для файла с таким содержимым:

```
Жизнь школы - это не только точные науки,
такие как алгебра, геометрия, физика или химия,
и не только гуманитарные (география, литература),
но и любимые нами рисование, трудовое воспитание,
а также факультативные: риторика и мировая культура.
```

выведет:

```
такие как алгебра, геометрия, физика или химия,
и не только гуманитарные (география, литература),
но и любимые нами рисование, трудовое воспитание,
```

Comment: Все таки подскажите, это все разные скрипты или разбитый один, простите за ламерство очень хочу разобраться, можно ли его привести к единому блоку как например тот что я давал в примере который ищет слово и выдает только одну строку, а нужно три, первая с искомым словом и две последующие, спасибо

Comment: да, можно, добавил... нужны будут пояснения - спрашивайте

Comment: @Саша теперь - оно?

Comment: да именно, но у меня не работает(

Comment: "не работает" ни о чем не скажет... @Саша, что пишет в трейсе?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(*lessons_list[i:i+3], sep='\n')
NameError: name 'lessons_list' is not defined

Comment: @Саша замените последнюю строку на ```print(*lines_list[i:i+3], sep='\n')```, исправил в ответе

Comment: Все заработало так как нужно, спасибо

Comment: @Саша супер! можете отмечать, как принятый ответ ))